# Подскажите книгу по С++

Tags: c++, книги

Подскажите книгу в которой нармально будет расказываться про структуры, шаблоны, указатели и классы. Читаю книгу Бориса Пахомова "C/С++ и MS Visual c++ 2010", В ней как то вскользь рассказывается.

Comment: Поищите по форуму, неоднократно обсуждалось

Comment: Используйте поиск, этот вопрос уже задавался несколько раз.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 0):

Ради интереса, посмотрел поиском по форуму. Наиболее полное обсуждение по этой теме.
Во многих ответах  советуют поискать по сети (или в форуме). Мрак.
Из тех книжек, что я видел - Бьерн Страуструп "Язык программирования С++. Специальное издание" мне показалась лучшей.